# Prove that this sequence is Cauchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n$ on the unit interval defined as follows. For $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3n}]$, $f_n(x)=-1$; for $x\in [\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3n}]$, $f_n(x)=3n(x-\frac{1}{2})$; for $x\in [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3n},1]$, $f_n(x)=1$. I'm trying to show that this sequence is Cauchy w.r.t. the norm $||f||=\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$.

Let $n>m$. Then $$0<A:=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3m}<B:=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3n}<\frac{1}{2}<C:=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3n}<D:=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3m}<1.$$
Further, $\int_0^1|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx=\int_{A}^{D}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx$ since $f_n-f_m=0$ outside the interval $[A,D]$. Now

\begin{multline}\int_A^D|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx=\int_A^B\left|1+3m\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|dx+\\+\int_B^C\left|3n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)-3m\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|dx+\int_C^D\left|1-3m\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|dx\end{multline}
In fact, as I write it, I realize that the previous computation might me unnecessary (but I'll leave it just in case). If we know that $|f_n-f_m|$ is bounded on $[A,D]$ by $M$, we can conclude that $||f_n-f_m||\le\frac{2M}{3m}\rightarrow 0$.  Is it true that $|f_n-f_m|$ is bounded? If so, how to see this? If not, how to finish the proof?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to show this for the 1-norm? This is common counterexample for $L^1$ convergence not implying $L^\infty$ convergence.

Comment: I meant "Cauchy", not "not Cauchy", fixed.

Comment: Ah. Jose's answer below implies Cauchy.

Comment: I  think there would be less computation to show that $\|f_n-f\|\to 0$ where $f(x)=-1$ for $x<1/2$ and $f(x)=+1$ for $ x>1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $f_n$ is something like:

[image]

Therefore, if $m>n$, the graph of $f_n-f_m$ looks like:

[image]

So, $\|f_n-f_m\|$ is twice the area of a triangle whith base $\frac1{3n}-\frac1{3m}$ and whose height is $\frac12$; that is $\|f_m-f_n\|=\frac16\left(\frac1n-\frac1m\right)$. This quantity becames arbitrarily small when $m>n\gg1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Cauchy, not "not Cauchy". I don't have a geometric picture in mind, that's why I tried to avoid "triangles".

Comment: @user500094 I've edited my answer.

Comment: May I ask how you obtained the graph of the difference (rather, how would you obtain it without a computer)? I have no problem with sketching $f_m$ and $f_n$ separately, but it's hard to say for me how the graph of $f_n-f_m$ looks like. Do I just need to use the definition of the difference and take many sample points? Or is there a shorter way?

Comment: @user500094 Both $f_m$ and $f_n$ are piecewise linear and therefore $f_m-f_n$ is piecewise linear too. In this specific case, all I hado to to was to compute $f_n-f_m$ at the points $0$, $\frac12\pm\frac1{3m}$, $\frac12\pm\frac1{3n}$ and $1$ and then to join the dots using line segments.